# How to pass data to a ClassFactory-generated instance in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, actionscript, mxml

I have created an item-renderer (IListItemRenderer) to customize the display of a datagrid, and I override the data getter/setter to pass in the relevant variable. So far, so good.

In the item-renderer I have a button, which, when clicked, should display a form populated with various fields of the aforementioned variable. To do this, Button is overridden so that it displays whatever IFactory implementation it is passed.

```
private function instantiateDropdown():void
{
    _dropdownFactory = new ClassFactory(MyPanel);
    _dropdownFactory.properties = {boundData: _myVariable};
}

<buttons:PopUpButton id="editButton" dropdownFactory="{_dropdownFactory}" toolTip="Edit" source="{skins.ButtonImages.Edit}" click="edit_clickHandler(event)" />
```

My IFactory implementation is a panel containing my form, and it is displayed when the button is clicked, as desired. However, the variable is not set. It seems that in order to instantiate my IFactory before the overridden button needs to access it, my new ClassFactory() statement needs to be in the preinitialize event handler, but the variable has not been set at that time. Setting the properties of my IFactory instance after it has been created (e.g. in the click event) does not appear to work.

How should I pass my variable to my ClassFactory-generated instance so that it populates the form correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Using lazy instantiation for the creation of the dropdownFactory (MyPanel in the question) in the class overriding Button (PopUpButton in the question), I was able to call instantiateDropdown in the creationComplete event instead of preinitialize, which allowed the PopUpButton to initialize with the correct properties (_myVariable in the question).